# Insert list of tuples sqlite python, error

Tags: python, sqlite, insert

This is my list of tuples, called "searchterms"

```
 [('2014', '100908'), ('2014', '101049'), ('2014', '101007'), ('2014', '100881'), ('2014', '100866')]`
```

Here is the code I am trying to use to insert these tuples into an sqlite database with only two columns named caseYR and caseNUM

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('searchdata.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Cases (caseYR TEXT, caseNUM TEXT)''')
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO Cases(caseYR, caseNUM) VALUES (?,?)", ("searchterms"))
conn.commit()
```

I have seen this question on StackOverFlow and numerous places online and the suggested solutions do not work for some reason.  Persistently getting this error:

```
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO Cases(caseYR, caseNUM) VALUES (?,?)", ("searchterms"))
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 2, and there are 1 supplied.
```

Please note I have seen I think all the similar questions on StackOverFlow and tried those options and obtained no success.  Any new ideas?

Comment: The `insert into Cases ... VALUES (?,?)` is looking for two values... You are only sending one string "searchterms".  I believe you should call it like so: `cur.executemany("INSERT...(?,?)", searchterms)`  if search terms is the variable name it should work

Comment: Searchterms is the name of the list of tuples.  Does that make a difference?  I have tried listing it with quotes around it and without.  Same result.

Comment: MitoxBeyond your suggestion changed the error message slightly to this:  "The current statement uses 2, and there are 4 supplied."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cursor.executemany` expects two parameters. The first parameter is the query. The second parameter should be an iterable of iterables of size equal to the number of bindings in the query. There are two `?` in the query, so that means there are two bindings. searchterms is an iterable (list) of iterables (tuples) of size 2, so it is a valid second parameter for `cursor.executemany`.

Originally, the second parameter was `("searchterms")` which failed because the string `"searchterms"` doesn't refer to the variable `searchterms`. Instead it was intepreted as an iterable (string) and since a string only has one character in each index, it gave the unhelpful error about supplying only 1 binding.

When you changed the second parameter to `searchterms`, it seems your `searchterms` variable was not a list of tuples, but rather a list of strings, which is why you got the error message stating you supplied 4 bindings. The string `'2014'` must've been the first item and has 4 characters in it.

The fix is to make sure that the second parameter you pass to `cursor.executemany` is indeed an iterable of iterables of size 2. Then MiltoxBeyond's suggestion will work.

I ran this and it worked:

```
import sqlite3

searchterms = [('2014', '100908'), ('2014', '101049'), ('2014', '101007'), ('2014', '100881'), ('2014', '100866')]

conn = sqlite3.connect('searchdata.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Cases (caseYR TEXT, caseNUM TEXT)''')
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO Cases(caseYR, caseNUM) VALUES (?,?)", searchterms)
conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this worked, but this code now works for me to take a list full of two item tuples and insert them into a table in an sqlite DB.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('searchterms.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Cases (caseyr TEXT, casenum INTEGER)''')
    cur.executemany('insert into Cases (caseyr, casenum) values (?,?)',tupledlist)
    conn.commit()
```